# Meteor loading collections in background

Tags: meteor

I use iron:router subscription hook to load needed data in every page of a meteor.js app (using subscription manager):

```
subscriptions: function() {
    return subman.subscribe("ElementsCurrentLang", Session.get('currentLang'), ['home']);
}
```

I would like also to preload other subscriptions (not all of them needed in the current page, but maybe part of them needed in current page) in background; I've tried to insert

```
globalSubs = {};
Meteor.subscribe("elementsCurrentLang", Session.get('currentLang'), function() {
    globalSubs.globalElements = true;
});
Meteor.subscribe("municipalitiesGlobal", Session.get('currentLang'), function() {
    globalSubs.globalMunicipalities = true;
});
Meteor.subscribe("culturalGoodsGlobal", Session.get('currentLang'), function() {
    globalSubs.globalCulturalGoods = true;
});
```

in a separate file subscriptions.js and added a test like the following to avoid re-subscripting to an already loaded subscription:

```
subscriptions: function() {
    if (!globalSubs.globalElements) return subman.subscribe("neededElementsCurrentLang", Session.get('currentLang'), ['progetto']);
},
```

but this doesn't work since the global subscriptions are loaded before the page's subscription and not in background;

is it possible to load the 3 global subscriptions in background, avoiding the app waiting for them to be loaded (it must wait only for the subscription's hook of the current route)?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  waitOn: function(){ 
  return [Meteor.subscribe('posts'),Meteor.subscribe('colors'),Meteor.subscribe('ads')];},
  yieldTemplates:{
    'header': {to: 'header'},
    'menu': {to: 'menu'},
    'footer': {to:'footer'}
  }
});
```

how about this.

Comment: it will load, all three subs on rout

Comment: this will load the three subscriptions before anything else